# How to create an optimizer in Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, tensorflow, mathematical-optimization

I want to write a new optimization algorithm for my network on Tensorflow. I hope to implement the [Levenberg Marquardt optimization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm), which now is excluded from TF API. I found poor documentation on how to write a custom optimizer, so i ask if someone can give my any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Damping factors have nothing to do with tensor flow. Neural networks have no need for ridge regression... I don't understand this community. +1 for shooting out a good heady question. For me providing a good answer would require some learning and that's my favorite aspect of SO.

Comment: did you ever manage to create you customized optimizer in TensorFlow? If you have a link to your code through github or something that would be super helpful!

Comment: dga's answer is useful if you want to make optimizers that are (presumably) faster and reusable between TensorFlow language interfaces, but if you just want to implement an optimizer in Python for use in Python, check out `ExternalOptimizerInterface`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ExternalOptimizerInterface

Comment: Could you accomplish your goal finally? I want to do the same and willing to hear your experience, Alberto. Thank you

Answer (score 18):

The simplest example of an optimizer is probably the [gradient descent optimizer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/gradient_descent.py).  It shows how one creates an instance of the basic [optimizer class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py).  The optimizer base class documentation explains what the methods do.

The python side of the optimizers adds new nodes to the graph that compute and apply the gradients being back-propagated.  It supplies the parameters that get passed to the ops and does some of the high-level management of the optimizer.  Then, you need the actual "Apply" op.

Ops have both a python and a C++ component.  Writing a training op is the same (but specialized) as the [general process of adding an Op to TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html).

For an example set of training ops that compute and apply gradients, see
[python/training/training_ops.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/training_ops.py) - this is the Python glue for the actual training ops.  Note that the code here is mostly about shape inference - the computation is going to be in the C++.

The actual math for applying the gradients is handled by an Op (recalling that, in general, ops are written in C++).  In this case, the apply gradients ops are defined in [core/kernels/training_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc).  You can see, for example, the implementation of ApplyGradientDescentOp in there, which references a functor ApplyGradientDescent:

```
var.device(d) -= grad * lr();
```

The implementation of the Op itself follows the implementation of any other op as described in the adding-an-op docs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a reason that this is done in C++? I don't see how composing this simple computation (scalar multiplication and element-wise subtraction) in C++ should be much faster than in Python. For prototyping optimizers, it would be useful to do everything in Python. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: @danijar the simple reason is that Python is only one of the available interfaces of Tensorflow. Implementing core mechanisms in C++ helps with creating interfaces for other languages.

Comment: sorry the code for tensorflow is really dense and confusing. So where exactly in the code can one find what mathematically the `apply_gradient` operations are doing? For example, I was reading https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py and it doesn't seem to have any mathematical expressions nor does the code for the gradient descent optimizer https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/gradient_descent.py. Where can I see how the apply gradient are being used?

Comment: This file offers a good example of how to implement an Optimizer class in Python: https://github.com/openai/iaf/blob/master/tf_utils/adamax.py

Answer (score 11):

Before running the Tensorflow Session, one should initiate an **Optimizer** as seen below:

```
# Gradient Descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

**tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer** is an object of the class **GradientDescentOptimizer** and as the name says, it implements the gradient descent algorithm.

The method **minimize()** is being called with a “cost” as parameter and consists of the two methods  **compute_gradients()** and then **apply_gradients()**.

For most (custom) optimizer implementations, the method **apply_gradients()** needs to be adapted.

This method relies on the (new) Optimizer (class), which we will create, to implement the following methods:  **_create_slots(), _prepare(), _apply_dense(), and _apply_sparse()**.

- **_create_slots()** and  **_prepare()** create and initialise additional 
  variables, such as momentum.
- **_apply_dense()**, and **_apply_sparse()** implement the actual Ops, which update the variables.

Ops are generally written in C++ . Without having to change the C++ header yourself, you can still return a python wrapper of some Ops through these methods.
This is done as follows:

```
def _create_slots(self, var_list):
   # Create slots for allocation and later management of additional 
   # variables associated with the variables to train.
   # for example: the first and second moments.
   '''
   for v in var_list:
      self._zeros_slot(v, "m", self._name)
      self._zeros_slot(v, "v", self._name)
   '''
def _apply_dense(self, grad, var):
   #define your favourite variable update
    # for example:
   '''
   # Here we apply gradient descents by substracting the variables 
   # with the gradient times the learning_rate (defined in __init__)
   var_update = state_ops.assign_sub(var, self.learning_rate * grad) 
   '''
   #The trick is now to pass the Ops in the control_flow_ops and 
   # eventually groups any particular computation of the slots your 
   # wish to keep track of:
   # for example:    
   '''
    m_t = ...m... #do something with m and grad
    v_t = ...v... # do something with v and grad
    '''
  return control_flow_ops.group(*[var_update, m_t, v_t])
```

For a more detailed explanation with example, see this blog post 
https://www.bigdatarepublic.nl/custom-optimizer-in-tensorflow/

Comment: hi @cyboroid, I am not sure how you are using the classes. Here is a quick colab notebook using the code from that blog post .https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pxnSn47taAxg7aRV374pipcstJJNtJ-t

Comment: Thanks. I am replying late, but your notebook worked and I am not sure what was it that I was doing wrong. Looks exactly the same as what I was doing.

Comment: @BenoitDescamps can you please share an example to do this in TensorFlow 2.0?