# tensorflow modify variables in py_func (and its grad func)

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow, we can define our own op and its gradient by:
https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342

However, can we modify any variable in the computational graph in these python functions. For example in the "_MySquareGrad" function?

I assume we can get the variable by:

```
var  = tf.get_variable('var')
```

and then do something to change its value and then assign it back?
e.g.

```
tmp = var*10
var.assign(tmp)
```

Thanks!

Also when we do var*10, do we have to convert it to numpy?

Background: I'm familiar with automatic differentiation, but new to Tensorflow and Python. So please point out any syntactic problem and let me know if my intention is clear.

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870727/can-one-only-implement-gradient-descent-like-optimizers-with-the-code-example-fr, basically just code ur update rule in tensorflow entirely.

Comment: Here's a following-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462376/pieces-of-numerically-identical-code-produce-drastically-different-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the variables in the computational graph in these python functions. Your example code with `tmp = var*10` will work and does not convert anything to numpy.

In fact you should try to avoid converting to numpy as much as possible since it will slow down the computation.

**edit:**

You can include your code to the gradient computation graph of the _MySquareGrad function doing this:

```
def _MySquareGrad(op, grad):

  #first get a Variable that was created using tf.get_variable()
  with tf.variable_scope("", reuse=True):
    var  = tf.get_variable('var')

  #now create the assign graph:
  tmp = var*10.
  assign_op = var.assign(tmp)

  #now make the assign operation part of the grad calculation graph:
  with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op]):
    x = tf.identity(op.inputs[0])

  return grad * 20 * x
```

Here is a working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
import numpy as np

# Define custom py_func which takes also a grad op as argument:
def py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=True, name=None, grad=None):

    # Need to generate a unique name to avoid duplicates:
    rnd_name = 'PyFuncGrad' + str(np.random.randint(0, 1E+8))

    tf.RegisterGradient(rnd_name)(grad)  # see _MySquareGrad for grad example
    g = tf.get_default_graph()
    with g.gradient_override_map({"PyFunc": rnd_name}):
        return tf.py_func(func, inp, Tout, stateful=stateful, name=name)

# Def custom square function using np.square instead of tf.square:
def mysquare(x, name=None):

    with ops.name_scope(name, "Mysquare", [x]) as name:
        sqr_x = py_func(np.square,
                        [x],
                        [tf.float32],
                        name=name,
                        grad=_MySquareGrad)  # <-- here's the call to the gradient
        return sqr_x[0]

### Actual gradient:
##def _MySquareGrad(op, grad):
    ##x = op.inputs[0]
    ##return grad * 20 * x  # add a "small" error just to see the difference:


def _MySquareGrad(op, grad):

  #first get a Variable that was created using tf.get_variable()
  with tf.variable_scope("", reuse=True):
    var  = tf.get_variable('var')

  #now create the assign graph:
  tmp = var*10.
  assign_op = var.assign(tmp)

  #now make the assign operation part of the grad calculation graph:
  with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op]):
    x = tf.identity(op.inputs[0])

  return grad * 20 * x



with tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.constant([1., 2.])

    var = tf.get_variable(name="var", shape=[], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.2))

    y = mysquare(x)
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    print(x.eval(), y.eval(), tf.gradients(y, x)[0].eval())
    print("Now var is 10 times larger:", var.eval())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very interesting. I thought tmp = var*10, if carried out by tensorflow, was a "mini computational graph". So I wasn't sure if we can embed this "mini computation graph" in the backpropagtion of a larger computational graph.

Comment: One question, when we perform this "var.assign(tmp)" in python. Does it take effect immediately? I thought tensorflow only constructs computational graph and waits until a sess.run() to evaluate the operation. since we are already inside the backprop execution of a larger graph, are we able to perform this "var.assign(tmp)" immediately? I'm confused because it's a mini computational graph within a larger graph.

Comment: @user21707 No it does not take place immediately. Just as you say it only constructs a computational graph that will be executed once sess.run() is used on this graph, or on a larger graph that includes the small graph. I added an example showing how to add your computational graph to the larger gradient-computation graph.

Comment: Thank you so much! I solved this issue with your suggestions.

Comment: However, I have do encounter another issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462376/pieces-of-numerically-identical-code-produce-drastically-different-results