# How to build bayesian network from ANN using tensorflow?

Tags: neural-network, bayesian-networks

I am a new in machine learning. I want to build bayesian neural network. I have artificial neural network before and I want to use it to build bayesian network. I try to do this because I want to compare the result of ANN and BN prediction result, so I think the structure of two programs must be same like in sum of epoch and sum of hidden layer, except in model structure or layer structure of ANN and BN. This is my ANN code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 10
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder('float')


def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                    'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])), }

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output


def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    # OLD VERSION:
    # cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
    # NEW:
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # OLD:
        # sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
        # NEW:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            for _ in range(int(mnist.train.num_examples / batch_size)):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

        correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))


train_neural_network(x)
```

I have read this [tutorial](https://github.com/mikkokemppainen/Jupyter_notebooks/blob/master/Edward_notebook_public.ipynb) about bayesian network but I don't understand enough. So, can I adapt ANN code above to build Bayesian Network?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late but if you are still on this work you can have a look to this paper https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1211-learning-bayesian-belief-networks-with-neural-network-estimators.pdf to have an idea of implementation to do and [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-to-bayesian-networks-with-jhonatan-de-souza-oliveira/) for smooth introduction with relevant reference

You may have to implement your own loss function and optimizer you should look at those answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875944/how-to-write-a-custom-loss-function-in-tensorflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431054/how-to-create-an-optimizer-in-tensorflow) to begin

I hope it will help !